# Redis-node : Ready check failed: NOAUTH Authentication required

Tags: node.js, security, redis

I am using the [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) package on npm after installing the redis from the digital ocean guide I secured it using [one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04) of their post. I set the requirepass to a password and then logged into my redis-cli and authenticated myself successfully. But I am unable to do the same from my Node.js application.

This is my config in Node

```
client = redis.createClient({
        no_ready_check: true,
        host : 'ip address',
        port : port
});
    client.auth('secretPassword', function(err, doc){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        else if(doc === "OK"){
            console.log("Authenticated");
        }
    });
    client.on('error' , function (err) {
        console.log("Error");

    });
```

After I run it. I get this error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReplyError: Ready check failed: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    at parseError (/home/ubuntu/demo/vehico-workers/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:181:12)
    at parseType (/home/ubuntu/demo/vehico-workers/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:291:14)
```

From my best guess, the node-redis driver doesn't implement it properly as I am able to authenticate from cli but not from Node application. Anybody who is running a secure redis.conf on AWS EC2 successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same probleme, and didnt find any solution on the Internet.

I change the directive pass to password in setting.js

```
redis: { host: "192.168.x.xx", password: '******', port: 6379 },
storageModule: require("node-red-contrib-redis-storage"),
```

And it work well.